# Adding Files/Folders to Program Files x86 Folder with C#

Tags: c#, file-permissions, program-files

I am trying to create a file directory (folder) in the 32 bit Program Files folder to store data that a user will be creating in the program.  However, it keeps saying that access is denied when I try to do so.  Is there anyway to give the program permission to access the 32 bit program files folder and add subsequent folder and files to it?  Here is my code below which is producing a run-time error due to not having permission.

```
string mainDirectory=Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86)+"\\UKC Trial Reporter Files";
if (!Directory.Exists(mainDirectory))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(mainDirectory);
}
```

Comment: you might have to run your program as an elevated process.

Comment: User data should not be stored under the Program Files directory.  If you use the user's directory (or ProgramData), you won't get an Access Denied error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Store your data in [`Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx), `Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData` or `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData` (if data have to be accessible by any user).

Never store it in %ProgramFiles%.
%ProgramFiles% is intended for... program files: executables, dlls, app.config files.

In addition of security reasons, there's yet another reason to do this never: when uninstalling, your application's installer **must** sweep all of files and folders it had created. And this is impossible, when list of files in installdir was changed during application lifetime.

Fortunately, we have UAC since Windows Vista has released.

Answer (score 4):

### **Don't do that**.

Program FIles is exactly that; it should contain EXEs and static resources.

Instead, you need to write to the user's `SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` folder.