# How to copy file in local disk c:

Tags: c#

When I am trying to create folder in this location `C:\Program Files` I get an Error. solve this problem or  how I can get windows Authorization in c# as below code

```
if(!(Directory.Exists(@"C:\Program Files\ClockResourse")))
{
   Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Program Files\ClockResourse");
}
```

Comment: You need to run as admin

Comment: As bitfiddler suggested, providing the error you're getting would help.

Answer (score 3):

You really should never create directories or anything else other than EXEs and static resources, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062062/adding-files-folders-to-program-files-x86-folder-with-c-sharp). If you absolutely had to, and depending on what type of program you are actually running you would have to require admin rights for the program, but without further information that's as far as I can help.